# Show/Hide image before filtering a table isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have web page with some really large tables that I'm filtering using some jquery routines I wrote. Anyway, when these tables get really large and the filtering functions can take some time to complete. So I figured I'd unhide a animated gif so the user had some feedback. However, the gif never appears when I call:

```
$('#loadingimg').show();
```

Unless I put an alert statement in front of it. I apologize for the ugly code, I'm not an experienced jquery/javascript programmer.

```
function filter()
{
    var eles = ["mtmprogram","rate","stage"];
    var tag;
    var classes='';

    $('#loadingimg').show();
//alert('hi');
    $('.report').hide();

    for (var i in eles)
    {
        tag = '#' + eles[i] + ' option:selected';
        if ($(tag).val())
        {
            //$('.'+ $(tag).val()).show();
            classes = classes + '.' + $(tag).val();
        }
    }
    if (classes == '')
        $('tr.report').show();
    else
        $(classes).show();

    filterSubtables('Loan Number');
    $('#loadingimg').hide();

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you aren't giving the `#loadingimg` element enough time to display. You could test this by running the rest of your code in a timeout:

```
function filter()
{
    var eles    = ["mtmprogram","rate","stage"],
        classes = '';

    $('#loadingimg').show();
//alert('hi');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.report').hide();

        for (var i = 0, len = eles.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            var $tag = $('#' + eles[i] + ' option:selected');
            if ($tag.val())
            {
                //$('.'+ $tag.val()).show();
                classes = classes + '.' + $tag.val();
            }
        }
        if (classes == '')
            $('.report').show();
        else
            $(classes).show();

        filterSubtables('Loan Number');
        $('#loadingimg').hide();
    }, 500);

}
```

Notice that I changed how the `tag` variable is used (this creates less CPU overhead to make less jQuery selections and to use as local a variable as possible). I also changed your loop to a better format that performs amazingly faster than `for ( a in b )`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Comment: Well, huh! Thanks for the programming tips!

Comment: The good news is the img is showing up when I have the timeout in there... but won't the timeout keep that code from completing if it goes too long?

Comment: Nope, the timeout just delays the execution of the code until the specified number of milliseconds, in this case 500 (or half a second). The code is then allowed to run as long as needed. Docs for ya on `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Well, that seems to work, although I don't know why. The filtering function takes several seconds to run. In fact, while it is running the animated gif stops spinning.

Any ideas on why that would stop spinning, or why I have to give it a half second to display before doing all that filtering?

Comment: Your loop is creating too much CPU overhead for the browser to animate the gif. You could try to put the iterations of your loop in a `setTimeout` so that there is a short break between iterations in which the gif image can be animated. You would do this by creating a recursively called function that called itself with a `setTimeout` to create the gap of time between loops, you can probably use a pretty small number of milliseconds like 10-100.